# How to debug <jsp:include> tag?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Is there a way to debug `<jsp:include>` tag?

I have a `container.jsp` that `jsp:include`s a servlet. `container.jsp` has a form within. When I get `container.jsp` by a GET request, `jsp:include` works fine and output from the target servlet is shown within. But when I get the `container.jsp` by a POST request, output from the target servlet isn't shown on the page.

The problem is that I can't figure out what exactly goes wrong with `jsp:include`. Why would it work fine in one situation and vanish quietly in another. I tried to turn on `org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl` logs with log4j at `TRACE` level but it din't show anything.

Is there any way/technique/tool to find out what goes inside `jsp:include` at runtime? Is there any alternative to `jsp:include` that is easier to work with? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: did you write outputting code in your servlet's `doGet()` only ?

Comment: Yes the target servlet's output comes by doGet() only. But how does it relate to the problem?

Comment: Cool! I have connected the outputting code with doPost() as well and now its working fine :D Many thanks for the hint! Please put your comment into an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make XXX request to page1.jsp which includes Servlet1 its `doXxx()` will be called

So for your case youd `doPost()` is being called which doesn't do anything as you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

you are generating your output using `doGet()` so it works fine when you get your jsp using `GET` request.

Create a method and call it from `doGet()` and `doPost()` in your servlet which generates output.

Then, It will work for POST as well as GET